# creating subscription with Microsoft Graph API error

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a subscription to receive notification about changes to Office365 Calendar. I have already worked with Outlook Notitication API but having a problem with Microsoft Grap API

I try to create a subscription using Http Post to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions with header and body:

- Header: Content-Type: application/json; Authorization : Bearer {accessToke}
- Body:

  {
  "resource": "me/calendars",
  "notificationUrl": "sample notification url",
  "changeType": "Created", 
  }

In my notification url, i've setup to send a response with the value of validation token when receveving a validation request

Finally, the result i received:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "There was an error processing a storage extension.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "6c563931-511d-415d-9c04-c07f25d45b1f",
      "date": "2016-03-20T08:10:32"
    }
  }
}

I wonder what I'm doing wrong or that's a internal error of MS Grap API. Can anyone help me? Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

The correct resource to use for calendar events is "me/events".  We'll try to get a better error message in future.